# Development Team is not fetched under developer account at XCode

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate, iphone-developer-program

I've been added to the apple development program (organization) as an Admin (with developer rights) via https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/

Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles has been granted for my account as well.

BUT, the only Team for my account I have - is my "Personal Team", while it should be able to pick another Development Team. I've been trying to remove the account, and add it to XCode accounts section over and over again, no luck.

Is there something I am missing so far?

MacOS: 10.15.7 (19H1713)

XCode: 12.4 (12D4e)

Comment: Same issue here. Yesterday was working, today not. Tried to re-add account but did not help.

Comment: I've contacted Apple Developer Support and they got it resolved. So, I suggest you to do the same.
So far, the issue wasn't on my side of things.

Comment: I did that and they told that they are aware of the problem and will let me know once they fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

After waiting for the Support to get back to me for two days, here is the answer that helped me, from the Apple Developer forum:

The following steps solved it for me:

- Go to the App Store Connect and select the team you don't have access to in Xcode.
- Go to the "Users and Access".
- Find yourself and click/tap your own name/user.
- Change the "Preferred Currency" to anything else (and back, if desired).
- Press "Save".
- Logout/Login into Xcode and you should be able to see the team now in the list.

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: Did work for me, legend!